# sysctl vs writing directly to /proc/*

Tags: linux, linux-networking, sysctl, proc

On a typical linux machine you can change kernel configuration by modifying the files located at `/proc/*`.

For example, for the IPv6 `accept_dad` parameter of a specific network interface (say, `eth0`), you'd modify the following file:

```
/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/eth0/accept_dad
```

But, as I recently discovered, there is the widely spread tool, `sysctl`, which has the same purpose, and works like so:

```
sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.eth0.accept_dad=1
```

My question is, when should we use which tool? My instinct says that if you know what you're doing, you should write to file directly but, if you would like validations and what not, you should use `sysctl`.

Since `sysctl` is yet another layer over something that we can control directly, I think by using it we're exposing ourselves to potential bugs that are otherwise avoided by writing to files directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sysctl` is a tool for reading and modifying various kernel attributes. It is available in many Unix-like operating systems, including not only Linux, but also OpenBSD and FreeBSD, for example. `sysctl` is typically available both as a shell command and as a system call.

In Linux, the `sysctl` mechanism is additionally exposed as part of the [procfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procfs) virtual filesystem, under `/proc/sys`.

Note that the `sysctl` syscall [is deprecated in Linux](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sysctl.2.html#NOTES); it is recommended to use `/proc/sys` instead (either directly or via the `sysctl` shell command).

References:

- [Manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sysctl.2.html) for the `sysctl` syscall in Linux
- [Manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/sysctl.8.html) for the `sysctl` shell command in Linux

Answer (score 0):

`sysctl` is a utility for interacting with `/proc`. In general, they accomplish the same thing. I would guess that years (decades?) ago, the only way to adjust kernel parameters was by editing the "files" in `/proc` by hand and `sysctl` came along later as a more civilized way of searching and modifying kernel params.

Of note, edits in `/proc` do not survive a reboot. This is handy if you are experimenting. The file `/etc/sysctl.conf` is a place to store your `sysctl` changes which you want to maintain across boot. If you really like editing the files instead, you may want to just make your changes there and call `sysctl -p` to execute the changes.